# How to Load Google's jQuery in External Script?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Stupid question, but does anyone know how to load google's jquery from an external script so it doesnt clunk up my header? In other words, I want to take the code below (probably starting at the google.load stuff and save it inside another file to include in my header. I want to keep my view source pretty :)

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=MySeCretKeyHere" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">google.load("jquery", "1.4.0");google.load("jqueryui", "1.7.2");
    google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){ $(document).ready(function(){ 
//onload stuff goes here
});});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as you say:

load.js:

```
google.load("jquery", "1.4.0");google.load("jqueryui", "1.7.2");
    google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){ $(document).ready(function(){ 
//onload stuff goes here
});});
```

html:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=MySeCretKeyHere" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="load.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```